# Как вернуть значение из вложенной функции?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Сейчас я использую код вида:

```
function getData(key, id)
{
    var data = '';

    $.get(
        'http://site.com/gate.php',
        {'key': key, 'id': id, 'action': 'get'},
        function (res) {
            data = res.split('|')[1];
        }

    return data;
}
```

Вопрос: можно ли как-то возвращать результат из замыкания передаваемого в `$.get(`)? Что-то вроде этого:

```
function getData(key, id)
{
    return $.get(
        'http://site.com/gate.php',
        {'key': key, 'id': id, 'action': 'get'},
        function (res) {
            return res.split('|')[1];
        }
}
```

Comment: Через глобальные переменные можно всегда.

А *return* для ajax'а вообще непонятно куда вернёт значение.

Comment: В данном случае будет лучше вариант с callback функцией

Comment: @WinterSilence У Вас запрос выполняется асинхронно, потому только через [Promise](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112960/)

Comment: @romeo так?
function getData(key, id)
{
    var jqxhr = $.get(
        'http://site.com/gate.php',
        {'key': key, 'id': id, 'action': 'get'}
    );

    return jqxhr.done(function(res) {
        return res.split('|')[1];
    });
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[[@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis)](/users/4058/deonis) всё правильно написал, но [поддержка браузерами нативных Promises](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) далека от идеала. Ждём [Spartan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartan_%28browser%29)

Существуют множество полифиллов, в том числе и для JQuery.

```
function getData(key, id){   
   var dfd = $.Deferred(),
       data =  {'key': key, 'id': id, 'action': 'get'};

   $.get('http://site.com/gate.php', data)
       .done(function (response) {           
           response = 'foo|bar|baz'; // предположим, что response вернул такую строчку
           dfd.resolve(response);
       })
       .fail(dfd.reject);

   return dfd;
}

getData(10, 100).then(function (response) {
    alert(response.split('|')[1]);
}, function (error) {
    // обработчик ошибок
});
```

[Смотреть результат здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/fsp3bsg8/)

#### Update

Вы можете явно указать, чтобы `$.ajax` возвращал вам синхронно, но такой подход в корне неверный.

```
function getData(key, id){ 
     var result;

     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://site.com/gate.php',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        data: {
            key: key,
            id: id,
            action: 'get'
        },
    })
    .done(function(response){
        response = 'foo|bar|baz'; // предположим, что response вернул такую строчку

        result = response.split('|')[1];
    })
    .fail(function(){
      // обработчик ошибок
    });

    return result;
}

alert(getData(10, 100));
```

[Смотреть результат здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/49m10shq/)

Comment: Поясню свою задачу - функция отправляет на сервер данные и получает id заявки, id передается в другую функцию, которая через некоторое время запрашивает у сервера ответ, т.е.

    var id = sendData(data); var result = loadResult(id);

Comment: @WinterSilence, какой-то день сумашествия... Ну, кто вам мешает отправить данные в какую-то другую функцию? Отправляйте её хоть в десяток.

Comment: @Deonis если вызвать loadResult(id) внутри sendData(data), то это все равно не решает проблему с возвращением результата ф-цией sendData

Comment: @WinterSilence Вы должны понимать, что JS, это асинхронный язык (т.е. некоторые команды могут не дожидаться выполнения предыдущих). Интерпретатор не ждёт пока запрос завершится, а дальше выполняет указанные инструкции/команды. Я Вам привёл синхронный пример выполнения `$.ajax` (смотрите Update), но за такое бьют по рукам.

Comment: @romeo я это понимаю, но как решить эту задачу при асинхронном подходе, не знаю, придется все-таки использовать async: false,

Comment: @WinterSilence Если совсем просто, то Вы должны все манипуляции с данными, которые поступили от сервера писать в `.done(function(response){ /* обработчик данных */ })` или же обработчик данных передать в `.done(success)`:

    var success = function (response) {
        alert(response.split('|')[1]);
    };
    
    $.ajax(...).done(success);

Comment: `$.get` **уже** возвращает промиз. Зачем использовать Deferred?

Answer (score 2):

```
function getData(key, id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://site.com/gate.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                key: key,
                id: id,
                action: 'get'
            },
            error: reject,
            success: function (res) {
                resolve(res.split('|')[1]);
            }
        });
    });
}

getData(10, 100).then(function (response) {
    console.log("Всё гуд!", response);
}, function (error) {
    alert('Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!: ' + error.statusText);
});
```

Comment: возвращаясь к первоначальному вопросу, а так можно?

    var id = getData(10, 100).then(
        function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        function (error) {
            alert('Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!: ' + error.statusText);
        }
    );

Comment: @WinterSilence Нет, нельзя, т.к. void

Comment: тогда, увы, данный вариант не приближает меня к решению проблемы. (

Comment: @WinterSilence, а вы можете описать причину, почему не подходит? [Смотрите пример][1]. Проверяете перед запросом, что содержится в переменной data, потом отправляете запрос и по его завершению опять проверяете. Значение изменилось и доступно глобально, как вроде бы вам и надо было.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/uf71gdgd/

Comment: @Deonis Поясню свою задачу - функция отправляет на сервер данные и получает id заявки, id передается в другую функцию которая через некоторое время запрашивает у сервера ответ. т.е. var id = sendData(data); var result = loadResult(id);

Comment: @WinterSilence, на это я уже ответил ниже. Короче, делайте синхронный запрос и будет вам счастье. Правда, счастья для юзера не будет.

Comment: @Deonis спасибо за ответы, этот код будет использоваться в персональном плагине для FF и, кроме меня, у него потребителей не будет. )